# What's the real meaning of the error "closure may outlive the current function"?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I wrote the following to test closures:

```
fn main() {
    let captured_val = "a captured value".to_string();
    let closure_parameter = "a parameter value".to_string();

    let mut ct = ClosureTest {
        cls: |closure_parameter| &captured_val,
    };
    println!("{}", (ct.cls)(&closure_parameter));
}

struct ClosureTest<T>
where
    T: FnMut(&str) -> &str,
{
    cls: T,
}
```

I got the following compile error:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `captured_val`, which is owned by the current function
 --> src/main.rs:6:14
  |
6 |         cls: |closure_parameter| &captured_val,
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ------------ `captured_val` is borrowed here
  |              |
  |              may outlive borrowed value `captured_val`
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `captured_val` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
  |
6 |         cls: move |closure_parameter| &captured_val,
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I added a lifetime parameter to the struct and it compiled and worked fine:

```
struct ClosureTest<'a, T>
where
    T: FnMut(&str) -> &'a str,
{
    cls: T,
}
```

Both variables (`captured_val` and `closure_parameter`) are in the same scope, but it seems like that the compiler does not see them having the same lifetime without the lifetime parameter `'a` I added to `ClosureTest<T>`. Is this because of Rust's lifetime inference with closures?

I don't understand the first line in the error message I got:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `captured_val`, which is owned by the current function
```

How could the closure outlive the current function? The closure is defined just in the current function, so I think the closure is going to be gone at the end of the current function.

What's the real meaning of the error message and why is it solved with adding the lifetime parameter as I did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The short version:** Adding explicit lifetime annotation makes a **guarantee** about `ClosureTest` which isn't necessarily implied without it.

---

## The long version

Assume you did this:

```
fn main() {
    let closure_parameter = "a parameter value".to_string();

    let returned_ct = do_something(v);

    println!("{}", (returned_ct.cls)(&closure_parameter));
}

fn do_something() -> ClosureTest {
    let captured_val = "a captured value".to_string();

    let mut ct = ClosureTest {
        cls: |param| &captured_val,
    };
    ct // !!!
}

struct ClosureTest<T>
where
    T: FnMut(&str) -> &str,
{
    cls: T,
}
```

On the line marked with `!!!`, notice that `ct` is *moved* out of the function as a return value. The object now 'lives' in `main`, but it contains a reference to something that is deleted when `do_something` ends. `ct.cls` is returning a *reference* to `captured_val`, which would no longer exist if `ct` is moved out of the function.

By modifying `ClosureTest` to include the lifetime, you are saying the following:

- A `ClosureTest` object `obj` has some lifetime `'a`
- The `str` reference returned by `obj.cls` lives for the entirety of the lifetime defined as `'a` on `obj`, if not longer
- Therefore, any reference returned by `obj.cls` has the same scope as the `ClosureTest` that returned it. `obj` will be dropped at the same time as the object its closure references, *or sooner*. In other words, any `ClosureType<'a, T> where T: FnMut(&str) -> &'a str` can only live while the object `T`'s return references exists, and must be dropped when that object is dropped.

The borrow checker doesn't get annoyed at the original value because `ct` and `captured_value` *have* different lifetimes, it's because they *could* have different life times - hence the 'may' in 'may outlive borrowed value `captured_val`'. When you add the lifetime parameter in your example, the borrow checker can now confirm that it should only compile if `captured_val` lives as long as `ct`, which it does (they are both dropped at the end of `main`).